# Boot xen server through ipxe

Tags: xen, xenserver, pxe-boot, ipxe

I'm want install Xen Server 6.2 though ipxe, I tried different configurations, no luck making to work until now.

I found some may example to boot from pxe using TFTP server, and here is an example:

```
default xenserver-auto
label xenserver-auto
    kernel mboot.c32
    append xenserver/xen.gz dom0_max_vcpus=1-2 dom0_mem=752M,max:752M com1=115200,8n1 console=com1,vga --- xenserver/vmlinuz xencons=hvc console=hvc0 console=tty0 answerfile=http://[pxehost]/answerfile.xml remotelog=[SYSLOG] install --- xenserver/install.img
```

The problem is that ipxe uses different syntax, I could not figure out how to convert this configuration to work on ipxe.

Here is my ipxe file so far:

```
#!ipxe

echo "XEN Server is booting up"
initrd http://server-ip/pxe/xen/boot/xen.gz
kernel http://server-ip/pxe/xen/boot/pxelinux/mboot.c32
boot
```

Can any one supply the correct configuration?

Answer (score 1):

not simple; you still have to play with pxelinux versions plus ipxe custom compilations. a real mess. Read this ipxe thread.

http://forum.ipxe.org/showthread.php?tid=6829

Comment: What I'm asking it booting the from the iso image or its content to install xen server, not booting an already installed one.

Comment: I know; my answer is valid in your case.

Answer (score 1):

From http://ipxe.org/cmd/kernel I would suspect that you can add the kernel options like this

```
kernel http://server-ip/pxe/xen/boot/pxelinux/mboot.c32 dom0_max_vcpus=1-2 dom0_mem=752M,max:752M com1=115200,8n1 console=com1,vga --- xenserver/vmlinuz xencons=hvc console=hvc0 console=tty0 answerfile=http://[pxehost]/answerfile.xml remotelog=[SYSLOG] install --- xenserver/install.img
```

Here is a similar setup w/o Xen Server http://jpmens.net/2011/07/18/network-booting-machines-over-http/. Its possible that the Server can't find xenserver/vmlinuz and/or install.img you can try to add the full http:// path or figure out whats the right location for ipxe to put those files.